# Name the maps in a commutative diagram

Tags: notation, article-writing

When writing a formal paper sometimes one needs to construct complicated commutative diagrams, such as

[image]

My question is, should one always give names to all maps in the diagram (perhaps except those starts with or ends with $0$)? Or is it okay to write some expression such as

For all $r\in R$, the image of $r$ under the composition $$R\to L\to \tilde{L}\to\tilde{L}/\tilde{R}\tilde{s}$$ is trivial, without giving names to all maps involved?

Comment: Do whatever is more clear.  Lots of papers and textbooks omit names of maps if the map is clear.  If there is any confusion then include the name.

Comment: Thanks @Seth! Is my example "For all $r\in R$, the image of $r$ under the composition $$R\to L\to \tilde{L}\to\tilde{L}/\tilde{R}\tilde{s}$$ is trivial" considered clear and acceptable in very formal writings?

Comment: I think it's clear assuming the reader already knows what maps are in the diagram you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @seth!!